# Executing a query when another is successful

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want my website visitors to attempt a quiz only once.I have two tables, `questions` and `attempted_students` .

`questions` consists of all the questions for the test.

`attempted_students` consists of student  details who have attempted the tests and their corresponding marks.Though the `id` field is a primary key which will automatically prevent further duplicate insertions but it is possible that a student can still take a test,he will be prevented only when he submits the test.

So I want to present him a message 'You have taken the test ' at the beginning if his id is present in the `attempted_students` table.

### My approach

To improve the performance by reducing the query into 1, I want to combine the queries like this

```
select if((select count(id) from attempted_students where id=1)>0,(select * from questions),'');
```

And then I am using

```
if(!empty($rows))
       //echo rows
else
       //sorry you have taken the test
```

But the above query is not working.So  need help to correct it.Secondly, please let me know if my approach will really improve the performance  than if I had executed the two queries seperately?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over optimizing.  And  putting conditions like that in the db isn't helpful in speeding up execution (they are subqueries and they are slow).

Just handle this in code.

```
select * from attempted_students where id=1

if(empty($rows)){
 select * from questions
 echo(rows)

} else {
     //sorry you have taken the test

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** , case Only aply on one operand at a time, and can return one value.

B/c your sub query result more than one result  so they will always return an error.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html

*You can do achieve this by making a **stored procedure** and there you can write if else block, and you will get desired flow.*

and Other option is to do it in php, executing second query only if first query result is positive.

**IF** used in select query is a function not a block statemnt.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the tables:

```
SELECT q.* FROM questions q
JOIN attempted_students s ON s.id = q.student_id
```

If you want to optimize, setting index to `q.student_id` should work well